# auto refresh taskbar

Tags: windows-xp

How do I auto-refresh taskbar, or whatever it is called.
Auto-refresh so that when you kill a certain process, it is automatically updated. And the icon that corresponds to that process also disappears in the taskbar after you killed the process. Is there any registry trick that could do that? In windows xp of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a registry entry exists, but it is [possible programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74723/can-you-send-a-signal-to-windows-explorer-to-make-it-refresh-the-systray-icons). You can utilize that code into a loop that runs in the background.